# ExportAsFixedFormat problems in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need help understanding the environment I'm in while using VBA. I'm looking to just print a PDF and no matter how simple the macro is, I get a Run-time error:

> '1004 Application-defined or object-defined error.

It inevitably puts the `ExportAsFixedFormat` 'paragraph' in yellow and gives me this error.

I've spent a week on this and I've simplified testing it to creating a completely new macro-enabled workbook, copying the macro into a module1 and running it. I've eliminated every possible problem with my environment and it is still giving me trouble. I even downloaded 64-bit when I was running 32 previously.

The only thing I can think of was adding a class module about a month ago for a licensing program. As far as I can see, it is no where to be found in my VBA app. Where would a class module or use form exist other than in the Project Explorer Tree?!!?

This is so frustrating because none of this has to do with the macro itself.

Comment: Always (OK, 99% of the time) helps to show the code you're having a problem with.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code. While you may say "no matter how simple" I hear, there's something missing. However, without the rest of your code, I cannot assess what the issue is accurately.

Comment: I just copied the code from below from Mark S. to demonstrate how many variables I've used when troubleshooting. I want to put focus on larger things beyond the code itself because whether I'm typing it to perform what I actually want or just copy one off the internet, it will inevitably bug out. ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FileName, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting a preliminary answer until you provide additional information (share your code). I may or may not come back to adjust this accordingly.

I have a file I export several sheets into a PDF format using their explicit names in an Array.

```
Sub PDF()
Dim FileName As String
Dim Name As String
Name = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table of Contents").Range("_Period")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
FileName = Left(FileName, Len(FileName) - 5) & " " & Name & ".PDF"

Sheets(Array("Table of Contents", "Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FileName, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Worksheets("Table of Contents").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I know using `.select` is frowned upon, but the purpose here is as my code cycles through these sheets, I want to land on the same tab I started in so I know it cycled properly and that's where my other buttons and macros are.